# How do you preserve formatting of `timestamptz` when converting to text/varchar

Tags: postgresql, string-formatting, timestamp-with-timezone

To get the current time with PostgreSQL, I have a simple query:

```sql
select now()::timestamptz
```

and an example output of that is

```
2022-06-15 23:43:41.418655 +00:00
```

However, when trying to work with this data in Java, this must be converted to Java's `String` type, which under the hood seems to cast `timestamptz` to `text` or `varchar`, which as you can see has different formatting:

```
2022-06-15 23:43:41.418655+00
```

(this is the same output with an explicit `select now()::timestamptz::text` or `select now()::timestamptz::varchar`; ***also***, this output happens in a PostgreSQL command in a command line/visual console, not something weird with Java or a library itself)

Is my only option to strip off the last 3 characters and append " `+00:00`" through Java, or is there a way I can modify my query to produce the desired results? (also I'm not sure if the `00`'s are guaranteed)

Note: This project uses PostgresQL version 10.21

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> select now()::timestamptz;
> ```

is just a noisy way of saying:

> ```
> select now();
> ```

`now()` already returns `timestamptz`.

To get your desired format as text, use [to_char()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US TZH:TZM')
```

In particular the [template patterns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) `TZH` and `TZM`.

And be aware that the output depends on the `timezone` setting of your current session - which happens to be UTC in your example, but that's inherently unreliable. You may want to define your time zone explicitly ...

Related:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: Your change returns `2022-06-16 15:26:41.764913 UTCH:UTCM`

Comment: That issue appears to be a matter of versioning, since TZH and TZM were only added in PostgresQL version 11

Comment: Goes to show the importance of dosclosing the Postgres version number in question ...

Comment: I wasn't aware my company was using an extremely outdated version, I'll check in the future

Comment: Not extremely outdated, your major version is still supported. https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ Upgrading to the latest version is typically beneficial, though. Would solve the issue at hand in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it matter?

Postgres can work with `2022-06-15 23:43:41.418655+00`:

```
select '2022-06-15 23:43:41.418655+00'::timestamp; 
06/15/2022 23:43:41.418655
```

or

```
select '2022-06-15 23:43:41.418655+00'::timestamptz; 
06/15/2022 16:43:41.418655 PDT
```

The data is not stored formatted in Postgres anyway. The formatting you see is for input/output purposes and is determined by your locale and `DateStyle` settings. It can be changed. The important part is that the values are correct.